# скроллинг списка категорий

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, тут такая проблема, нужно настроит скроллинг. Есть выпадающий список категорий, там 45 категорий, но контент обрезается и дальше никуда не скроллиться. пробовал через CSS не сработало, пробовал через JS тоже самое, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: Результат кода на JS]

```js
let parentCategoryScroll = document.querySelector('#oct-menu-ul'),
    childCategoryScroll = document.querySelectorAll('.oct-menu-child-ul');

parentCategoryScroll.style.overflowY = 'scroll';

for (let i = 0; i < childCategoryScroll.length; i++) {
childCategoryScroll[i].style.overflowY = 'scroll';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #oct-menu-ul {
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-height: 500px;
    }

   .oct-menu-child-ul {
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-height: 500px;
    }
```